# Building a built-in text field for turtle, while statement doesn't work

Tags: python, input, text, turtle-graphics

I have built a text field module that has one problem: why does Python IDLE not work for while...break statements?

Originally I didn't have a break statement and this didn't work so I added the break statement and the same problems persisted.

This is a long script. You will need everything in it.
Do not run in repl.it, as it will not run. However it does run on IDLE.

https://repl.it/@SUPERMECHM500/TextField

As commented in the script, the while statement at line 610 doesn't load on IDLE, and the `break` doesn't work as expected: Continue the code if the TextField.FullOutput object has text.

None of my problems relate to repl.it so don't mention it in your answers.
Run and debug this script as a Text file from python IDLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a few minor issues:

```
def listenforkeys(bool):
```

`bool` is a Python keyword, choose a different variable name.  (E.g. `flag`.)  This `or` doesn't work the way you think:

```
if TextField.FullOutput and TextField.inp != "" or []:
```

Reread about `or`.  Don't use the same turtle for `TextField` implementation that you use for `TextField` utilization as this statement:

```
t.clear()
```

wipes out all the actions done with `t` by user of `TextField`.  Use a different turtle.  Finally, your call to `mainloop()` is in the wrong place.  Once you invoke it, your code stops and the tkinker event handler takes over.  It generally should be the last thing your code des.

Now the main issue, this utilization code:

```
while TextField.FullOutput == "": #Hope this works with Windows IDLE...
  tm.sleep(0.1)
  print("Waiting for input...")
  if TextField.FullOutput != "":
    print('Data sent to RAM.')
    break
```

Don't loop waiting on the buffer to fill.  This really should be an *event*, but at least a *callback*.  I've rewritten your code below to make this a callback, see the `Enter()` function and example usage code. It now works for me in IDLE and at the command prompt.  I've also made lots of other little changes to try to clean it up a bit -- some of these may need further testing...

```
# Text field that can be used universally.
# Created by SUPERMECHM500 @ repl.it
# Full functionallity can only be achieved by using IDLE on Windows.

from turtle import Screen, Turtle, mainloop

class TextField:
    TextFieldBorderColor = '#0019fc'
    TextFieldBGColor = '#000000'
    TextFieldTextColor = '#ffffff'

    ShiftedDigits = {'1':'!', '2':'@', '3':'#', '4':'$', '5':'%', '6':'^', '7':'&', '8':'*', '9':'(', '0':')'}

    def __init__(self, callBack=None):
        self.callBack = callBack
        self.turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
        self.turtle.speed('fastest')
        self.inp = []
        self.FullOutput = ""
        self.TextSeparation = 7
        self.s = self.TextSeparation
        self.key_shiftL = False

    def DrawTextField(self, Title):
        t = self.turtle
        t.pensize(1)
        t.color(TextField.TextFieldBorderColor)
        t.pu()
        t.goto(-200, -190)
        t.write(Title)
        t.goto(-200, -200)
        t.pd()
        t.goto(200, -200)
        t.goto(200, -250)
        t.goto(-200, -250)
        t.goto(-200, -200)
        t.pu()
        t.goto(-200, -225)
        t.color(TextField.TextFieldBGColor)
        t.pensize(48)
        t.pd()
        t.forward(400)
        t.pu()
        t.goto(-190, -220)
        t.color(TextField.TextFieldTextColor)

    # Defines the function for each defined key.
    def ShiftLON(self):
        print("Capslock toggled.")
        self.key_shiftL = not self.key_shiftL

    def Space(self):
        self.turtle.write(' ')
        self.inp.append(' ')
        self.turtle.forward(self.s)

    def Backspace(self):
        try:
            self.inp.pop(-1)
        except IndexError:
            print("Cannot backspace!")
        else:
            t = self.turtle
            t.pensize(15)
            t.color(TextField.TextFieldBGColor)
            t.forward(10)
            t.backward(self.TextSeparation)
            t.shape('square')
            t.pd()
            t.turtlesize(1.3)  # <<< Doesn't work on repl.it
            t.stamp()
            t.pu()
            t.color(TextField.TextFieldTextColor)
            t.shape('classic')
            t.backward(10)

    def Period(self):
        if self.key_shiftL:
            self.turtle.write('>')
            self.inp.append('>')
            self.turtle.forward(self.s)
        else:
            self.turtle.write('.')
            self.inp.append('.')
            self.turtle.forward(self.s)

    def Comma(self):
        if self.key_shiftL:
            self.turtle.write('<')
            self.inp.append('<')
            self.turtle.forward(self.s)
        else:
            self.turtle.write(',')
            self.inp.append(',')
            self.turtle.forward(self.s)

    def Enter(self):
        if self.inp != []:
            print("Joining input log...")
            self.turtle.pu()
            self.FullOutput = ''.join(self.inp)
            print('joined.')
            print(self.FullOutput)
            print("Output printed.")

            try:
                self.callBack(self.FullOutput)
                print("Data sent to callback.")
            except NameError:
                print("No callback defined.")

            self.turtle.clear()
            print("Display cleared.")

    def digit(self, d):
        if self.key_shiftL:
            d = TextField.ShiftedDigits[d]

        self.turtle.write(d)
        self.inp.append(d)
        self.turtle.forward(self.s)

    def letter(self, abc):
        if self.key_shiftL:
            abc = abc.upper()

        self.turtle.write(abc)
        self.inp.append(abc)
        self.turtle.forward(self.s)

    def listenforkeys(self, flag):  # Whether or not keys are being used for text field.
        s = Screen()

        if not flag:
            for character in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
                s.onkey(None, character)

            for digit in '0123456789':
                s.onkey(None, digit)

            s.onkey(None, 'period')
            s.onkey(None, 'comma')
            s.onkey(None, 'Shift_L')

            # s.onkeyrelease(None, 'Shift_L')

            s.onkey(None, 'space')
            s.onkey(None, 'BackSpace')
            s.onkey(None, 'Return')

            if self.FullOutput or self.inp:
                self.FullOutput = ""  # Reset the text field content
            self.inp = []  # Reset input log

            print("Stopped listening.")

        if flag:
            for character in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
                s.onkey(lambda abc=character: self.letter(abc), character)

            for character in '1234567890':
                s.onkey(lambda d=character: self.digit(d), character)

            s.onkey(self.Period, 'period')
            s.onkey(self.Comma, 'comma')
            s.onkey(self.ShiftLON, 'Shift_L')

            # s.onkeyrelease(self.ShiftLON, 'Shift_L')

            s.onkey(self.Space, 'space')
            s.onkey(self.Backspace, 'BackSpace')
            s.onkey(self.Enter, 'Return')

            s.listen()

            print("Listening.")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    def text_callback(text):
        print("Data received by callback.")
        textField.listenforkeys(False)
        turtle.pu()
        print("Pen up.")
        turtle.write(text, align='center', font=('Arial', 30, 'normal'))
        print("Text written.")

    screen = Screen()
    screen.setup(500, 500)

    textField = TextField(text_callback)
    textField.DrawTextField("Enter Text. Note: Shift is capslock. Capslock disables your keys.")
    print("Text field drawn.")

    textField.listenforkeys(True)
    print("Can type.")

    turtle = Turtle(visible=False)

    mainloop()
```

Comment: I do appreciate this, so since this is a module, I want to do certain events in my code like `DrawTextField("")` and in the next line I start the event. I wrote this intentionally to be used universally. In your code, what is the syntax for waiting for user input? (e.g. while...)

Comment: @DakotaPlemmons, you don't *wait* for user input, you define a callback function for when user input arrives.  Do you see anything in turtle or tkinter that *waits* for something to happen?  Generally, we register functions to be called when events occur.

Comment: 1) is the `if __name__ == '"__main__":` required? 2) can the `text_callback(text)` be refined inside of itself?

Comment: @DakotaPlemmons, the `__main__` stuff is there to separate what is part of the ultimate module from what is simply testing code -- that's a *good* thing.  I'm not sure what you're asking with respect to `text_callback()` but there could be a `TextField` method that the user passes the name of the function they want called when text is available.

Comment: for the `text_callback`, could you _redefine_ `text_callback()` inside of itself? Like I can run the function but I want it to run again but in a different way after pressing enter. Similar to making a multi-step program, like logging into an email service.

Comment: @DakotaPlemmons, reread the second part of my previous comment.  Add a method to `TextField` via which the user of the module registers a function of theirs that should be called when text is available.  Each `TextField` instance can have their own callback function and you can switch to a different function by registering it instead later.  No redefining functions inside of themselves needed.

Comment: Where do I add this Method? Can I get an example? Sorry I didn't say it before but I am novice with python. Still good though.

Comment: @DakotaPlemmons, I've done another (hopefully final) pass through the code in my answer.  I've reworked it to be an object class -- no longer an object class with associated global variables, global functions and singular instances.  I've updated the example usage code accordingly.  The callback function is now passed in as part of creating a `TextField`.  You can supply a different callback later when you create a new `TextField` instance.

Comment: Thank you, however the only thing that doesn't work on my IDLE is turtle(visable=False). I prefer to just hide the turtle with t.ht() just after creating it. other than that it's good. would you like to join my discord for coding? Really no one but me is in it. I can use it for personal help and/or tutoring. - Please consider upvoting my question.