# Python - Creating an instance of a module, getting an error

Tags: python, module

I am creating a universal text field that can be used in many python turtle projects. I am trying to create an instance of it but I get this error:

```
>>> import TextField
>>> tf = TextField('None', False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    tf = TextField('None', False)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
>>>
```

What in a module causes this type of error? I completely wrote this module and I'm getting an error creating an instance of it :( ... What do I need in this module to make it 'callable'? I have tried adding a `def __call__(self):` but that doesn't affect the problem at all, nor create any errors.
Here is the beginning of the script where the problem is most likely happening:

```
# Created by SUPERMECHM500 @ repl.it
# Edited by cdlane @ stackoverflow.com

class TextField:
    TextFieldBorderColor = '#0019fc'
    TextFieldBGColor = '#000000'
    TextFieldTextColor = '#ffffff'

    ShiftedDigits = {
                     '1':'!',
                     '2':'@',
                     '3':'#',
                     '4':'$',
                     '5':'%',
                     '6':'^',
                     '7':'&',
                     '8':'*',
                     '9':'(',
                     '0':')'
                    }

    def __init__(self, command, CanBeEmpty): # Ex. textField = TextField('Execute()', True)
        self.CmdOnEnter = command
        self.turtle = Turtle()
        self.CanBeEmpty = CanBeEmpty
        self.turtle.speed('fastest')
        self.inp = []
        self.FullOutput = ""
        self.TextSeparation = 7
        self.s = self.TextSeparation
        self.key_shiftL = False

......
```

Comment: The module is not the class. If your class `TextField` is in a module called `TextField`, then it is referred to as `TextField.TextField`. Or you need `from TextField import TextField`.

Comment: @khelwood Make that an answer. You just saved my life.

Comment: "I completely wrote this module..." -- I thought I wrote a [huge chunk of this module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54636304/5771269) for @DakotaPlemmons

Comment: @cdlane oh you are here! Sorry I forgot to credit you for that. I'll do that now. I am Dakota, this is just another account. That is my school account!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module is not the class. If your class `TextField` is in a module called `TextField`, then it is referred to as `TextField.TextField`.

Or change your import to

```
from TextField import TextField
```